# Multiple updates for Unity animation per one method call

Tags: unity, animation, animator

I'm trying to do some simulation where I move objects procedurally in a loop within one method call. So instead of using Update(), method I do for example:

```
void Simulate(float deltaTime)
{
   // real logic look a lot different, this is just an example
   for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
   {
      transform.position += direction * speed * deltaTime;
   }
   .....
}
```

The reason I'm doing this is because I want consistent 'framerate' by passing that deltaTime parameter; Which is for example 0.01f;
And each step of that loop I'm taking snapshots on multiple cameras with calling Render() method on them before taking a picture. The movement works fine and I see it on snapshots, but some objects has an animation which should also be updated procedurally.

I've tried to do

```
animator.speed = 0;
```

and then in the same loop, to test it

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; ++i)
{
   ...
   animator.Play("WalkFWD", 0, i/1000f); //for example
}
```

But animation does not change over that loop. It only works with that Play method when I either make this Simulation() method a coroutine and pass one frame (yield return null), or if I use in Update(). 
So, my question: is it possible to procedurally update/redraw animation after normalized time of that animation is set. (without waiting for another frame)

Comment: Does [Animator.Update()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.Update.html) behave any differently for you than Play()?

Comment: @DMGregory, yes. If I do it in a loop within one Unity frame and capture snapshots with camera, then I can see that the animation doesn't change the avatar pose.

Comment: @DMGregory,  `void OnSimulationTick(object sender, SimulationTickArgs args)
    {
        currentState.Update(args.deltaTime);  
        anim.Update(args.deltaTime);  
    }`  I trigger an event, which OnSimulationTick is subscribed to, multiple times within the same unity frame.